Question on a characterization of compact operators


Question:
In the proof above of the implication (iii) $\implies $(iv), why is it easy to see that  $x_M \rightarrow 0$ weakly?


Here is a typed version of the above image using an AI:
Theorem 5. Let $ T \in \mathcal{B}(X, Y) $. The following conditions are equivalent:

$ T $ is compact;

if $(x_\alpha) $ is a net of elements of $ B_X $ and $x_\alpha \to 0 $ weakly, then $ \|T x_\alpha\| \to 0 $;

the restriction $T|_{B_X} $is a continuous mapping from $ B_X $ with the weak topology into $ Y $with the norm topology;

for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a closed subspace $M \subset X $ with $\operatorname{codim} M < \infty $ such that
$$
    \sup \left\{ \|T x\| : x \in M, \|x\| = 1 \right\} \leq \varepsilon.
    $$


Proof.
$1. \Rightarrow 2.$: Let $(x_\alpha)$ be a net of elements of $B_X$, $x_\alpha \to 0$ weakly. It is easy to show that also $T x_\alpha \to 0$ weakly. Suppose on the contrary that $\|T x_\alpha\| \not\to 0$. Then there exists a positive constant $c$ and a subnet $(x_{\alpha_\beta})$ such that $\|T x_{\alpha_\beta}\| \geq c$ for all $\beta$. Since $\overline{T B_X}$ is compact, the net $(T x_{\alpha_\beta})$ has an accumulation point $y$. Clearly, $\|y\| \geq c$. On the other hand, $T x_{\alpha_\beta} \to 0$ weakly and so $y = 0$, a contradiction.
$2.\Rightarrow 3.$: Let $(x_\alpha) \subset B_X$, $x_\alpha \to x$ weakly. Then $x_\alpha - x \to 0$ weakly, and so $\|T x - T x_\alpha\| \to 0$. Hence $T x_\alpha \to T x$ in the norm topology.
$3. \Rightarrow 4.$: Suppose that (iv) is not true, so there exists $c > 0$ such that, for every closed subspace $M \subset X$ of finite codimension, there exists $x_M \in M$ with $\|x_M\| = 1$ and $\|T x_M\| \geq c$. Consider the net $(x_M)_M$ directed by the inclusion, $M \geq M' \Leftrightarrow M \subset M'$. It is easy to see that $x_M \to 0$ weakly and $\|T x_M\| \not\to 0$.
$4.\Rightarrow 5.$: Suppose that $T$ is not compact, so there exists $c > 0$ such that $T B_X$ cannot be covered by a finite number of balls of radius $c$. Choose $x_1 \in B_X$ arbitrarily and construct inductively a sequence $(x_i)$ of points in $B_X$ such that $\|T x_i - T x_j\| \geq c$ for all $i, j \in \mathbb{N}, i \neq j$. Clearly, $\|x_i - x_j\| \geq \frac{c}{\|T\|}$.

This is an interesting result. Would you mind mentioning which book this is from? It also may be preferred in future if you type up the part you are unsure about rather than use large images to display important parts of your question. See here.

I have added a typed version of the image generated by an AI

For every weakly open neighborhood $V$ of the origin there exists $f_1 ,\dots, f_N \in X^*$ such that the closed subspace $M:= \bigcap_{j=1}^N\ker f_j \subset V$. Note that $M$ has finite codimension.  Hence $x_{M'} \in M' \subset M \subset V$ belongs to every weakly open neighborhood of the origin for $M' \ge M$.

Thank you for your response, but I still don't understand why the codimension of this M is finite.

@abelcool  The kernel of a functional has codimension one and the intersection of finite codimensional spaces has finite codimension

Thank you for your answer. I understand now.
